# Jump to the top of the page on pagechange function?

Tags: javascript, forms, function

I'm trying to set up "pages" (using visible/hidden divs) and everything works properly, except for when the BACK button is clicked from the 2nd page (after scrolling down to the bottom of that page), it lands in the middle of the 1st page, and I need it to jump to the top of that page.  The NEXT button lands the subsequent pages at the top, which is perfect.

Below is code for 2 demo pages exhibiting this problem... any help would be greatly appreciated!

NOTE: The tables and spaces are there intentionally to replicate the shell environment this form will ultimately sit in on the site.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <script>


    function pagechange(currentPage) {
     var divs=document.getElementsByTagName("div");
     for(var i=0;i<divs.length;i++){
       if(divs[i].id!=('formpage_'+(parseInt(currentPage)+1))){
          divs[i].style.display="none";
          divs[i].style.visibility='hidden';
       }else{
         divs[i].style.display="block";
         divs[i].style.visibility='visible';
       }
     }
   }

  </script>
</head>

<body>
 <form action="..">
                        <p>&nbsp;</p>
                        <p>&nbsp;</p>
                        <p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
                        <p>
                          <!-- the first page has style set to be visible -->
                        </p>
                        <table width="1164" height="1051" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                          <tr>
                            <td><div id="formpage_1" style="visibility: visible; display: block; ..">
                              <table width="158%" height="806" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="10">
                                <tr>
                                  <td colspan="2"><h2>APPLICANT INFORMATION</h2></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                  <td width="32%" class="interiortext">*Required Field</td>
                                  <td width="68%">&nbsp;</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                  <td align="right" class="interiortext">Mailing  Address Line 2</td>
                                  <td class="interiortext"><input type="text" name="textfield13" id="textfield21" /></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                  <td align="right" class="interiortext">City</td>
                                  <td class="interiortext"><input type="text" name="textfield13" id="textfield20" /></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                  <td align="right" class="interiortext">State</td>
                                  <td class="interiortext"><input type="text" name="textfield13" id="textfield19" /></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                  <td align="right" class="interiortext">Zip Code</td>
                                  <td class="interiortext"><input type="text" name="textfield13" id="textfield18" /></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                  <td class="interiortext">*Do you have a co-applicant?</td>
                                  <td><table width="200">
                                    <tr>
                                      <td width="79" class="interiortext"><label>
                                        <input type="radio" name="lived2years" value="radio" id="lived2years_2" />
                                        Yes</label></td>
                                      <td width="109" class="interiortext"><input type="radio" name="lived2years" value="radio" id="lived2years_1" />
                                        No</td>
                                    </tr>
                                  </table></td>
                                </tr>
                              </table>
                              <!-- NEXT button -->
                              <input type="button" value="next" onclick="pagechange(1);" />
                            </div></td>
                          </tr>
                        </table>
                        <!-- the 2nd and following pages have style set to be invisible -->
<div id="formpage_2"  style="visibility: hidden; display: none; ..">
                          <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="10" cellpadding="0">
                            <tr>
                              <td colspan="2"><h2>&nbsp;</h2>
                              <h2>&nbsp;</h2>
                              <p>&nbsp;</p>
                              <p>&nbsp;</p>
                              <p>&nbsp;</p>
                              <p>&nbsp;</p>
                              <h2>&nbsp;</h2>
                              <h2>CO-APPLICANT INFORMATION</h2></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td width="32%" class="interiortext">*Required Field</td>
                              <td width="68%">&nbsp;</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td colspan="2" class="interiortext">*First Name
                                <input type="text" name="textfield14" id="textfield23">
                                &nbsp; MI
                                <input name="textfield14" type="text" id="textfield24" size="2">
                                &nbsp; *Last Name
                                <input type="text" name="textfield14" id="textfield25">
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td align="right" class="interiortext">*Date of Birth</td>
                              <td class="interiortext">
                                <input type="text" name="textfield14" id="textfield26">
                                &nbsp; (mm/dd/yy)</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td align="right" class="interiortext">State</td>
                              <td class="interiortext">
                                <input type="text" name="textfield14" id="textfield56">
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td align="right" class="interiortext">Zip Code</td>
                              <td class="interiortext">
                                <input type="text" name="textfield14" id="textfield55">
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td class="interiortext">*Is the co-applicant a first-time homebuyer?</td>
                              <td><table width="200">
                                <tr>
                                  <td width="79" class="interiortext">
                                    <label>
                                      <input type="radio" name="lived2years" value="radio" id="lived2years_11">
                                      Yes</label>
                                  </td>
                                  <td width="109" class="interiortext">
                                    <input type="radio" name="lived2years" value="radio" id="lived2years_12">
                                    No</td>
                                </tr>
                              </table>
                              <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
                            </tr>
                          </table>
                          <!-- PREVIOUS and NEXT buttons -->
                          <input type="button" value="back" onClick="pagechange(0);">

                        </div>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might result in an awkward page scroll when you click back button, but it'll certainly not let the page to be scrolled down to middle of the document.

Add this in HTML:

```
<body onload="myFunction()">
```

And this in the `<script>` tag:

```
<script>
  function myFunction() {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }
</script>
```